# Retrieve serial ID with Npgsql when inserting with ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I'm trying to insert a row into a PostgreSQL table with a serial primary key and I need to retrieve this column after it was inserted. I got something like this:

The table "pais" has 3 columns: id, pais, capital; id is a serial column and is its primary key.

```
NpgsqlCommand query = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into pais(nombre, capital) values(@nombre, @capital)", conn);
query.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("nombre", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
query.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("capital", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
query.Prepare();
query.Parameters[0].Value = this.textBox1.Text;
query.Parameters[1].Value = this.textBox2.Text;
Object res = query.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

It inserts the row on the table but "res" value is null. If I insert with the nexval('table_sequence') also returns null.

Any idea of how can I return the id of the table? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't read your query as "selecting" any value to return as scalar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to select the last identity inserted you need to use: `currval(sequencename)`

so your select statement should look like:

```
NpgsqlCommand query = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into pais(nombre, capital) values(@nombre, @capital);select currval('table_sequence');", conn);
```

Comment: Excelent! I tryied with lastval() and works but without the query.Prepare() line, just like the post that you linked. Thanks!

Comment: I would expect that the "INSERT INTO table (fieldnames) VALUES (values) RETURNING idcolumn?" from @mlapaglia is a much better solution.

Answer (score 27):

Is that thread safe?
What if another insert happens between your insert and select?
Why not use:

`INSERT INTO table (fieldnames) VALUES (values) RETURNING idcolumn`?

Comment: it is thread safe if the select is in the same query becuase it is in the same "session", from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-sequence.html: "Because this is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether or not other sessions have executed nextval since the current session did."

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me. This one did, so thanks for adding it.

Comment: Why is it that sometimes it returns -1 even though it created a record in the DB?

Answer (score 22):

```
insert into pais(nombre, capital) values(@nombre, @capital) RETURNING id
```

replace `id` with your primary key`enter code here` and use

```
Object res = query.ExecuteScalar();
```

Inside `res` you'll have the PK.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. You need to cast it to a long like so:
long lastID = (long) commandObj.ExecuteScalar ();

Answer (score 3):

The insert itself does not cause a value to be returned. When you perform ExecuteScalar it is looking for a single value to be "Selected" so to speak.

I believe you need to follow up your insert with a select statement to solve your issue.
If you were using t-sql you would do this like so

string sql =
        "INSERT INTO [Table] (FieldName) VALUES (@ParamName); "
        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";

ExecuteScalar would then return the unique id;

I am not sure of the exact syntax for postGresql but hopefully this allows you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check how to do that on postgres

Comment: It should be string sql = "INSERT INTO [Table] (FieldName) VALUES (@ParamName); " + "SELECT CAST(lastval() AS integer)";

Comment: Great. Thanks for the clarification of the exact syntax.  Sorry. I've been lost in sql server land for years. :)

Comment: Don't worry. It gave me the idea.

Comment: lost in SQL translation perhaps?