# Problem with ExecuteScalar with Npgsql insert

Tags: c#, postgresql

I', trying to insert a row into a PostgreSQL table with a serial primary key and I need to retrieve this column after it was inserted. I got something like this:

The table "pais" has 3 columns: id, pais, capital; id is a serial column and is its primary key.

```
NpgsqlCommand query = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into pais(nombre, capital) values(@nombre, @capital)", conn);
query.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("nombre", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
query.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("capital", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
query.Prepare();
query.Parameters[0].Value = this.textBox1.Text;
query.Parameters[1].Value = this.textBox2.Text;
Object res = query.ExecuteScalar();
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

It inserts the row on the table but "res" value is null. If I insert with the nexval('table_sequence') also returns null.

Any idea of how can I return the id of the table? I am missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should ask this on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: So. What is programmers about?

Answer (score 1):

It was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583517/problem-with-executescalar-with-npgsql-insert/5583935#5583935). The way is using a "Select currval()" or a "Select lastval()" just after the insert statement.