# Return last inserted ID in postgresql with c#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I a function that inserts a record in a table, and i want to get the insered ID.
How can I do? I have to make a new query?

```
        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AxWaveConnection"].ToString()))
        {

            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();


            String query =
            "INSERT INTO Video (youtubeidvideo, title, rating, viewcount, duration, dataadded, errorflag, schedulingflag, schedulingdate, convertdate) " +
            "VALUES ('" + youtubeIdVideo + "','" + title + "'," + rating.ToString().Replace(',', '.') + "," + viewCount.ToString() +  "," +
            duration.ToString() + ", now(), false, false, null, null); ";

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn, transaction);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                scopeID = -1;        //Duplicate Record
            }

            transaction.Commit();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: In order to select the last identity inserted you need to use: `currval(sequencename)` I would also suggest that you refactor the `Insert` Statement to utilize `Parameterized Query` looking at the way that the query is setup you could experience errors with the `now()` see if your `NpgsqlCommand` supports `Parameters.AddWithValues` here is a good stack overflow link as well [NpgSqlCommand Return Last Inserted Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583517/problem-with-executescalar-with-npgsql-insert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT CURRVAL(pg_get_serial_sequence('my_tbl_name','id_col_name'))
```

You need to supply the table name and column name of course.

This will be for the current session / connection

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-sequence.html

You can check this also

See the RETURNING clause of the [INSERT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-insert.html) statement. Basically, the INSERT doubles as a query and gives you back the value that was inserted.