# Inserting JSON Column with auto-incrementing field in Postgres?

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, npgsql

First, please forgive me if I use the wrong terms, I'm *very* new to both PostgreSQL and NoSQL-style data storage. Moving on:

I'm using npgsql to connect a .NET project to a PostgreSQL database. We're using it as a NoSQL document storage, with our tables consisting of a primary key `id` column and a jsonb object in the `data` column, nothing else.

In the `data` column, we also want a way of generating an id field which auto-increments on each insert. This id doesn't necessarily need to match the primary key, but that's sort of the assumption off of which I'm working.

I've been able to make this work in pgadmin using the following scripts:

```html
drop table public.testjson;
drop sequence public.testjson_id_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.testjson_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE public.testjson_id_seq
  OWNER TO login;

CREATE TABLE public.testjson
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('testjson_id_seq'::regclass),
  data jsonb,
  CONSTRAINT testjson_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE public.testjson
  OWNER TO login;


-- Insert data using currval --
INSERT INTO testjson (data) VALUES( to_jsonb('{"jsonid": '||currval('testjson_id_seq'::regclass)::bigint||', moreStuff: "all the stuff!"}'));
INSERT INTO testjson (data) VALUES( to_jsonb('{"jsonid": '||currval('testjson_id_seq'::regclass)::bigint||', moreStuff: "all the stuff!"}'));
INSERT INTO testjson (data) VALUES( to_jsonb('{"jsonid": '||currval('testjson_id_seq'::regclass)::bigint||', moreStuff: "all the stuff!"}'));
INSERT INTO testjson (data) VALUES( to_jsonb('{"jsonid": '||currval('testjson_id_seq'::regclass)::bigint||', moreStuff: "all the stuff!"}'));
select * from testjson

-- Output -- 

id | data
---------------------------------------------------------
1  | "{\"jsonid\": 1, moreStuff: \"all the stuff!\"}"
2  | "{\"jsonid\": 2, moreStuff: \"all the stuff!\"}"
3  | "{\"jsonid\": 3, moreStuff: \"all the stuff!\"}"
4  | "{\"jsonid\": 4, moreStuff: \"all the stuff!\"}"
```

So far, so good. I think I'm going to refactor this so the jsonid field has its own sequence and use `nextval` instead of `currval` (to prevent race conditions resulting in duplicates), but the question isn't about that. I'm having trouble replicating this on the code side. Looking around at other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583517/retrieve-serial-id-with-npgsql-when-inserting-with-executescalar) here led me to believe that this might work:

```html
var crcmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO "+_schema+"."+table+" ("+JsonColumn+") VALUES (:json) RETURNING id;", _conn);

var jsonData = getSerializedJsonData(thing, primaryKey);
crcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("json", NpgsqlDbType.Jsonb, jsonData);

returnId = (long) crcmd.ExecuteScalar();

...

private string getSerializedJsonData<T>(T thing, string primaryKey, string tableSeq)
{
    var jsonThing = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing);

    var bracketIndex = jsonThing.IndexOf('{');
    var thingPrefix = jsonThing.Substring(0, bracketIndex + 1);
    var thingData = jsonThing.Substring(bracketIndex + 1);
    var pkEntry = "\"" + primaryKey +"\": currval('" + tableSeq + '::regclass)::bigint, ";
    jsonThing = thingPrefix + pkEntry + thingData;
    return jsonThing;
}
```

But when I try to test it, the following exception is thrown:

`Npgsql.PostgresException: 22P02: invalid input syntax for type json; Token "currval" is invalid`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Turned out there were two things I needed to fix.

The first one was the conversion to jsonb. I didn't notice before, but if you look at my postgres output, the `data` column is being saved as a string instead of a jsonb object. That is fixed easily by replacing `to_jsonb('...')` with `('...')::jsonb`.

The second task was to make it work in C#. In order to do that, I had to change the way the `NpgsqlCommand` is being created: In order to get access to the `currval` value I have to pass the command text as raw text, rather than parameterizing it as I'd originally tried to do. So the final, working code looks more like this:

```html
var jsonData = getSerializedJsonData(thing, primaryKey);
var crcmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO "+_schema+"."+table+" ("+JsonColumn+") VALUES (('+jsonData+')::jsonb) RETURNING id;", _conn);

returnId = (long) crcmd.ExecuteScalar();

...

private string getSerializedJsonData<T>(T thing, string primaryKey, string tableSeq)
{
    var jsonThing = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing);

    var bracketIndex = jsonThing.IndexOf('{');
    var thingPrefix = jsonThing.Substring(0, bracketIndex + 1);
    var thingData = jsonThing.Substring(bracketIndex + 1);
    var pkEntry = "\"" + primaryKey +"\": currval('" + tableSeq + '::regclass)::bigint, ";
    jsonThing = thingPrefix + pkEntry + thingData;
    return jsonThing;
}

-- Output (truncated) -- 
id | data
--------------------------------------------------------
1  | { IsActive: true, "DisplayName": "configUser", "UserLoginId": 1", "PasswordHash":... 
2  | { IsActive: true, "DisplayName": "WDCGVBNESSAULSAZLIVR", "UserLoginId": 2", "Pass...
3  | { IsActive: false, "DisplayName": "UJMFANMOSHPNDQSEUEGL", "UserLoginId": 3", "Pas...
4  | { IsActive: true, "DisplayName": "SOQDFTZVHPHXIXDVQJTS", "UserLoginId": 4", "Pass...
5  | { IsActive: true, "DisplayName": "WFPUMCRBRPDHSQALMKPW", "UserLoginId": 5", "Pass...
6  | { IsActive: true, "DisplayName": "HVBEGQSSFJWCJYCCLMXI", "UserLoginId": 6", "Pass...
```

Comment: Inserting the data into the query directly as a string breaks the cardinal rule of databases. Did you ever find a better solution?